# How can I set the selected index of a comboBox base from its valueMember? (C# Window Form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a comboBox that displays different Municipalities (these Municipalities belongs to a particular Province) in our country. Since there are Municipalities having the same name, I binded the "MunicipalityName" (a table column from 'MUNICIPALITY' table in my database) to DisplayMember property of the comboBox and "Municipality_ID" to ValueMember property of the comboBox.

When the user saves his details, I supply the SelectedValue from ValueMember of the MUNICIPALITY and insert it to Employee table.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Municipality_ID", (object)comboBoxMunicipality.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

I find it hard when it comes to retrieval of data when an Employee needs to update his information. I have to manually check the Municipality_ID of that employee and compare it to the binded data in the comboBox, then loop through it, determine what index that Municipality_ID located, and set the SelectedIndex property of the comboBox. (Quiet lengthy compared to code snippet below)

I have this code, but I find conflicts since Municipality_Name is not unique.

```
//set SelectedIndex based from DisplayMember of the comboBox    
comboBoxMunicipality.SelectedIndex = comboBoxMunicipality.FindStringExact(dataTable.Rows[0]["MunicipalityName"].ToString());
```

Is there a way to set the SelectedIndex of the comboBox like the code above, but this time, comparing it to the ValueMember?

Is there a shortcut?

```
     //something like this?
comboBoxMunicipality.SelectedIndex = 
    comboBoxMunicipality.FindByValue(dataTable.Rows[0]["Municipality_ID"].ToString());
```

I hope you get my point guys... Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
comboBoxMunicipality.SelectedValue = theMunicipalityIDtoSelect
```

Comment: how simple, haha, thank you sir... I'm just a newbie in programming. Thanks again : )

Comment: No problem, Yonan - enjoy the simplicity, sir!